# When Importing Self Made Vue 3 Library Into Vue 3 Project: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE')"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

I created a custom component library using Vue 3, and after installing it locally thru yarn and registering the components, I kept getting the following error in the browser devtools when using the components in the template:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE')

Upon researching the issue, it became apparent that the Vue community's proposed [solution](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4344) isn't working. I'm running the same Vue 3 version on both projects. I followed the steps to create and modify vue.config.js to alias Vue and disable symlinks, but to no avail.

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack(config) {
    config.resolve.symlinks(false);
    config.resolve.alias.set("vue", path.resolve("./node_modules/vue"));
  },
};
```

I followed the rabbit hole which only led to the same conclusions: either modifying vue.config.js worked, or no solution was found. The issue (mainly) seems to be with components with slots.

Comment: Make sure it installs correctly... Check out the node_modules and packet.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try vite instead of vue-cli to create your custom lib. and keep your **vue** stay at devDependencies in Package.json

Comment: When you say "keep your vue stay at devDependencies in Package.json", do you mean have it as a devDependency in the consuming app? I have a vite component library that I'm trying to consume in a Nuxt 3 app.

Comment: No, consuming app still use Vue in Denpendency.

Comment: Vite and vue-cli were giving me the same problem, but yes using devDependencies is the solution.

Comment: Putting `vue` into `devDependencies` in both my master (monorepo root) `package.json` file as well as the sub-package `package.json` file solved my error.  Many thanks Alex!

Answer (score 0):

for me this solution solved it inside vite.config

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
          vue: path.resolve('./node_modules/vue'),
        },
        dedupe: ['vue'],
      },
```