# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE') - Custom Component Library

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-component, vuejs3, vite

I am having trouble building a custom component library for Vue 3 using ViteJS and NPM. I have included a basic illustration of my issue below, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction, I have been stuck on this for 2 days :(.

My folder structure:

- dist
- node_modules
- src

  - components

    - Paragraph.vue
  - paragraph.js
- .gitignore
- package.json
- README.md
- vite.config.js

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "paragraph",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "The paragraph test component.",
  "main": "./dist/paragraph.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/paragraph.es.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/paragraph.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/paragraph.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.1",
    "vite": "^2.9.5"
  }
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/paragraph.js', import.meta.url)),
      name: 'Paragraph',
      fileName: (format) => `paragraph.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue'
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
  },
})
```

**paragraph.js**

```
import Paragraph from './components/Paragraph.vue';

export default {
  install: (app) => {
    app.component('Paragraph', Paragraph);
  },
};
```

**Paragraph.vue**

```
<script setup>
  console.log('Test');
</script>

<template>
  <p class="paragraph">
    <slot />
  </p>
</template>

<style>
  .paragraph
  {
      color: black;
  }
</style>
```

When I run `npm run build` it works successfully and creates the correct files, I then include the es file into my test Vue project as a plugin.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Paragraph from '../../paragraph/dist/paragraph.es.js'

createApp(App).use(Paragraph).mount('#app')
```

The component doesn't work when used liked this.

```
<Paragraph>Hello World 2!</Paragraph>
```

The following error is reported back in the console.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE')
```

I have looked into the issue and it seems a lot of people have had the same issue, although I cannot find a fix for myself.

I have tried the solutions mentioned in the following links:

https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4344

[When Importing Self Made Vue 3 Library Into Vue 3 Project: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063992/when-importing-self-made-vue-3-library-into-vue-3-project-uncaught-typeerror)

**Neither of the solutions mentioned here are working.**

Can someone please help!!!

I have noticed if I exclude the `<slot />` it works fine, but slots are vital to components.

I know it is bundling the Vue code into the build file, but how do I stop it doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

I've also encountered this very frustrating issue. According to [this answer](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4344#issuecomment-899064501), it is caused by having Vue imported from multiple packages instead of using just one singleton, as you do suspect.

Presumably, you are building your consumer application using Vite. In that case, setting the `dedupe` option in its `vite.confg.js` should solve it.

```
resolve: {
  dedupe: [
    'vue'
  ]
},
```

Comment: Hi Greegus, thank you for your reply. I am not sure if your solution works but it makes sense that it would, I added the following line of code to the consumer application's vite.config.js file as an alias. 'vue': fileURLToPath(new URL('./node_modules/vue', import.meta.url)). This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I just checked this solution, adding dedupe: ['vue'] also corrects the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Pointing out to the [Library Mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) documentation. Make sure your `vite.config.js` looks like:

```
  build: {
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'lib/main.js'),
      name: 'MyLib',
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: 'my-lib',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Fixed it for me! Underrated answer here. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

The issue is there are multiple instances of vue are loaded with different versions.

In the case of my error, the issue is module resolution are loaded dependencies, for example, Vue in a direct project dependency is version 3.3.7.
Another package (eg. `public-ui-fw`) uses vue version 3.3.6.

In this case, package manager is installing.

```
package.json
node_modules/
    vue/
        package.json # this is version 3.3.7
    public-ui-fw/
        package.json
        node_modules/
            vue/
                package.json # this is version 3.3.6
```

So the `public-ui-fw` is using a different instances of vue.

---

Solution,

I forced package manager to install only 1 version across all transitive dependencies.

Depends on package manager you're using, please refer to:

- https://bun.sh/docs/install/overrides
- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides
- https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove node_modules + yarn.lock
And then reinstall packages (yarn)

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions above and none succeeded.

What did the trick for me was moving away from the [semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning).

So if you have in your package.json something like `"vue": "^3.4.0"` or `"vue": "~3.4.0"`, just place the version as `"vue": "3.4.0"`, then remove the `node_modules` folder and run the install again.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this issue :) the problem is you have two distinct copies of the Vue package being used

just read this and you will find your answer. for me, changing the workspace to yarn was the solution.

https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4344

Answer (score 0):

In my case, moving the "vue" dependency to be a dev dependency solved the issue.